# Multiple classes added on Chrome but not Edge Or IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

In the following code, I append a class twice depending on a boolean value. In chrome it works flawlessly yet in Edge and IE, only the body recieves the `backgroundNight` class and the foregorund elements do not recieve the  `foregroundNight` class.

[Example found here](http://trystanr.github.io/)

```
function toggleMode() {
            if (bNightMode) {
                bNightMode = false;

                document.getElementById("nightmode").src="img/moon-white.png";
                document.getElementById("nightmode").style.backgroundColor = "#2c3e50";

                //make day mode

                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundC");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].classList.remove("backgroundNight");
                }

                var m = document.getElementsByClassName("ForegroundC");
                var n;
                for (n = 0; n < m.length; n++) {
                    m[n].classList.remove("foregroundNight");
                }

            } else {
                bNightMode = true;

                document.getElementById("nightmode").src="img/moon-black.png";
                document.getElementById("nightmode").style.backgroundColor = "#ecf0f1";

                //make night mode

                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundC");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].classList.add("backgroundNight");
                }

                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ForegroundC");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].classList.add("foregroundNight");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: We'd need the HTML too... From just that, looking at your class names I'd guess you mistakenly added a capital F to ForegroundC and that it should be foregroundC instead. Chrome is just being permissive on that.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer to explain it better for prosperity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this line

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ForegroundC");
```

It finds all elements that have the class `ForegroundC` but the problem is that in your HTML, it is authored `foregroundC`, so in internet explorer it does not get found, therefor the class `foregroundNight` does not get applied.

Be careful with class names... Browsers are a bit like operating systems on that. Windows does not differentiate the case, but linux does...

Comment: Never mind.  [Working now :)](https://github.com/Trystanr/Trystanr.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: This is the only difference between the background and foreground code so it has to work if one works... Anyways, I will not run down all your code... Also, by the way, you'd be a lot better to just have a class on your body to set day/night and simple use cascading styles instead of using javascript for that.